# Dúvida ao migrar código Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar esse trecho de código do Gulp 3 para o Gulp 4. Tudo antes funcionava perfeitamente, fui atualizar a lib por vulnerabilidades e agora fica aparecendo o seguinte erro: (Não consegui entender a [documentação](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/) de migração)

[image: Erros no console ao executar o gulp]

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('scripts', ['static'], () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('static', ['clean'], () => {
    return gulp
        .src(['src/**/*.json'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return gulp
        .src('dist')
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('build', ['scripts']);

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], () => {
    return gulp.watch(['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.json'], ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela documentação do Gulp, parece que a maior mudança na API é que agora você decide se os scripts devem ser executados em ordem ou em paralelo, então ao invés de utilizar essa sintaxe:

```
// Gulp 3
gulp.task('scripts', ['static'], () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Você usará essa:

```
// Gulp 4
gulp.task('scripts', gulp.series('static', () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));
```

Ou ainda, se a ordem da execução dos scripts não importar, você pode executa-los em paralelo com:

```
// Gulp 4
gulp.task('scripts', gulp.parallel('static', () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui chegar ao seguinte código:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return gulp
        .src('dist/*')
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('static', gulp.series('clean', () => {
    return gulp
        .src(['src/**/*.json'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));

gulp.task('scripts', gulp.series('static', () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('scripts'));

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    return gulp.watch(['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.json'], gulp.series('build'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build','watch'));
```

O problema fica no terminal, onde é mostrado algumas mensagens sobre a execução dele. Nestas mensagens aparece um , em vez de aparecer o devido nome da tarefa.

[image: Mensagens do terminal!]